# ParcelJS: Cannot find module error randomly

Tags: reactjs, typescript, parceljs

This happens randomly. When I edit a tsx file (e.g. a data view page), next time I render the web page, it says `Error: Cannot find module '../../component/primitive/TextBox'` (or some other primitive react component that is already there).

I have tried re-running the parcel command and removing the `dist` folder but none of them helped. The only solution is to remove `.parcel_cache` folder and rerun `parcel serve` command, after which everything works just fine (unless next random time that it fails with similar error).

Any idea why this happens?